Sub-additiviy of the log-Sobolev constant without independence
If two random variables $X$ and $Y$ verify the log-Sobolev inequality, what can we say about the log-Sobolev constant of their sum $X+Y$?
If they are independent, we know that
$$
c_{LS}(X+Y) \leq c_{LS}(X) + c_{LS}(Y)
$$
from results on stability under convolution. Does a weaker sub-additivity hold without independence ? Can we show that the following holds
$$
\sqrt{c_{LS}(X+Y)} \leq \sqrt{c_{LS}(X)} + \sqrt{c_{LS}(Y)}.
$$
We know this is true for the weaker Talagrand's $T_2$ inequality by exploiting the subadditivity of subgaussian norms. Can it hold for the LSI as well?

As there are different conventions, I consider the log-Sobolev constant defined as follows
$$
KL(\nu, \pi) \leq \frac{c_{LS}(\pi)}{2} I(\nu, \pi).
$$
